# Grammar definition for search keywords

Tags: antlr, grammar

I'm looking for some help writing a grammar definition to match words separated by '&' or spaces, kinds like:

"aaa bbb", "aaa & bbb", "aaa   bbb   & ccc", " aaa&ccc  ", etc

The problem here is that a space and a '&' means the same an AND but rest of spaces need to be ignored.

Speaking more generally I'm trying to write a grammar for expressions string like google advanced search has in their search.

Current code (not working):

```
grammar Query;

options {
    language = CSharp3;
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

tokens {
    Minus = '-' ;
    And = '&' ;
    Or = '|' ;
}

/*-- PARSER RULES ------------------------------------------------------------*/

public expr
    : Keyword (and Keyword)*;

and 
    : IgnoredWhiteSpace (And | WhiteSpace) IgnoredWhiteSpace ;


/*-- LEXER RULES -------------------------------------------------------------*/

Keyword : Char Char Char+ ;

//WhiteSpace : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C')+ ;

WhiteSpace : ' ' ;

IgnoredWhiteSpace : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C')+  { $channel = Hidden; } ;

fragment Char : ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '\u0410'..'\u042F' | '\u0430'..'\u044F' | '.') ;
```

Comment: "some help" = I don't know how to write this, whitespace has two meanings depending the context...

Comment: That seems like a regular language. Why not just use regular expressions?

Comment: The sequence of words separated by & or ' ' is just the beginning, i need to support nested parentesis of all this or and not operators...

Answer (score 1):

Do not place references to IgnoredWhitespace in the grammar (the grammar won't see those because of `$channel=HIDDEN`), and make the `And` optional with `(And)?`.